# doctrine2 (xml): in a one-to-many bidirectional relationship, can't get the infers side?

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

i have `Banner` and `Group` entities with xml configs

Banner.xml

```
<mapped-superclass name="Banner" table="luc_banners"
                   repository-class="BannerRepository">
    <id name="id" column="id" type="integer">
        <generator strategy="AUTO" />
    </id>
    <field name="path" column="path" type="string" nullable="true" />
    <field name="link" column="link" type="string" nullable="true" />
    <field name="position" column="position" type="string" nullable="true" />
    <field name="groupId" column="group_id" type="integer" />

    <many-to-one field="group" target-entity="Group" inversed-by="banners">
        <join-column name="group_id" referenced-column-name="id" nullable="false" on-delete="CASCADE" />
    </many-to-one>
</mapped-superclass>
```

Group.xml

```
<mapped-superclass name="Group" table="luc_banners_groups" repository-class="GroupRepository">
        <id name="id" column="id" type="integer">
<generator strategy="AUTO" />
        </id>
        <field name="name" column="group_name" type="string" nullable="true" />
        <field name="type" column="group_type" type="string" nullable="true" />
        <field name="status" column="group_status" type="string" nullable="true" />
        <field name="order" column="group_order" type="integer" nullable="true" />
        <one-to-many field="banners" target-entity="Banners" mapped-by="group">
            <cascade>
                <cascade-all />
            </cascade>
        </one-to-many>
    </mapped-superclass>
```

when trying to get banners form group object i get empty array, and Profiler shows this sql `SELECT l0_.group_name AS group_name0, l0_.id AS id4 FROM luc_banners_groups l0_ WHERE l0_.group_status = ?` and show not valid entity with this error `Banner - The association Banner#group refers to the inverse side field Group#banners which does not exist.`

Can you help me with this thing ?

Answer (score 0):

remove `<field name="groupId" column="group_id" type="integer" />` from `Banner.xml`, I think it's overriding the second one..

Comment: @HaykAramyan Try to set `entity` instead of `mapped-superclass`, to see it works or not.. [Doctrine doesn't support 1:n relationship](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses), BUT `Sylius` uses it somehow..

Comment: same error `The target-entity Banners cannot be found in 'Group#banners'.`

Comment: yes, now i'm using `Sylius`, with the Sylius `Product` class my variant is working, but with custom Entities no

Comment: @HaykAramyan Has your custom entity been located in `Entity` directory?

Comment: nope, am using `model` folder, and all namespaces are ok, do you think it can be the reason of my error ?

Comment: @HaykAramyan may be.. Symfony reads from Entity folder by default, try to use `addCompilerPass`, or try move them to Entity folder..

Comment: @HaykAramyan try to use `addCompilerPass`, example (AcmeDemoBundle.php):
public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $mappings = array(
        realpath(__DIR__ . '/Resources/config/doctrine/model') => 'Acme\DemoBundle\Model',
    );

    $container->addCompilerPass(DoctrineOrmMappingsPass::createXmlMappingDriver($mappings, array('doctrine.orm.entity_manager'), 'sylius_core.driver.doctrine/orm'));
}